# jsoup reading data that is not present

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a html page that I am reading.
If the format I am reading in that page is not present I want to exit and continue with the next page but that is not working.

can you please let me know what I am missing

```
try
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlget).get();
    Element tables = doc.select("div.itembody");
    websiteaddress= tables.text();
}
catch (IOException ee)
{
}
```

If the get is not having itembody I am seeing a exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
I want this loop to be continued not the program exsit when there is a exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`doc.select`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) returns an object of type `Elements` (a list of Elements) not `Element`. If no element in your html matches the query you get an empty list of elements. Change your code to:

```
try
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlget).get();
    Elements tables = doc.select("div.itembody");
    if(tables.isEmpty())
        noDivItembodyInHTML();
    else
        websiteaddress = tables.first().text();
}
catch (IOException ee)
{
}
```